# A problem with regards to the sum of the digits of a number

Tags: summation, arithmetic, arithmetic-functions

The problem says the following: Let $S(n)$ be the sum of digits of some number $n  \in \Bbb N^*$. Find a natural number $k$, such that $S(k)=2017 \times S(3k) $. (The sum of the digits of a number is defined as summing the digits once in this case).

I have no idea what to do and where to start solving this.

Comment: "I have no idea what to do and where to start solving this." Then, it would be the most natural thing to forget it. Or to study some more.

Comment: $3k=10^{6049}+10+7, S(k)=18153,S(3k)=9$
$$S(k)=2017\cdot S(3k)$$